# awk command not working for rbash user

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, symbolic-link

I have created a rbash user(restricted user) vega and I have created softlinks for the following commands-: awk,ls,free,top etc. Am trying to run a script for resource utilization and some of the commands use awk.

If I run the below commands via admin am able to get the results:

```
admin@VD1-21-2-1:/home/vega$ free -m |grep Mem |awk '{print $3/$2 * 100.0}'
16.4827
admin@VD1-21-2-1:/home/vega$ top -b -n 1 -d1 |grep "Cpu(s)"| awk -F' ' '{print $2}'|awk -F' ' '{print $1}'
0.3
```

When I execute them via restricted user which I have created, I get below errors:

```
vega@VD1-21-2-1:~$ free -m |grep Mem |awk '{print $3/$2 * 100.0}'
-su: /usr/bin/awk: Permission denied

vega@VD1-21-2-1:~$ top -b -n 1 -d1 |grep "Cpu(s)"| awk -F' ' '{print $2}'|awk -F' ' '{print $1}'
-su: /usr/bin/awk: Permission denied
-su: /usr/bin/awk: Permission denied
```

I have used the following commands for soft link below:

```
sudo ln -s /bin/ls /home/vega/bin 
sudo ln -s /bin/top /home/vega/bin 
sudo ln -s /bin/free /home/vega/bin 
sudo ln -s /bin/awk /home/vega/bin 
sudo ln -s /bin/ssh /home/vega/bin
```

How to resolve this permission denied error and the command should give the correct output.

Replying to @terdon:
Hi @terdon I tried your step and am getting as below:

```
vega@VD1-21-2-1:~$ echo $PATH /home/vega/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
without sudo it is not working: 

admin@VD1-21-2-1:/home/vega$ ln -s /bin/ls /home/vega/bin ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/vega/bin/ls': Permission denied
```

tried via root also:

```
root@VD1-21-2-1:~# ln -s /bin/ls /home/vega/bin ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/vega/bin/ls': File exists
```

Simple I want a restricted user to access all my commands without any issues?

Comment: What softlinks did you create, exactly? Please [edit] your question with enough information for someone to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I have used the following commands for soft link below:

sudo ln -s /bin/ls /home/vega/bin
sudo ln -s /bin/top /home/vega/bin
sudo ln -s /bin/free /home/vega/bin
sudo ln -s /bin/awk /home/vega/bin 
sudo ln -s /bin/ssh /home/vega/bin

Comment: Please ***EDIT*** your question and include this information there. Comments are hard to read, easy to miss and can be deleted without warning. Next, please delete the links you created and then create new ones without using `sudo`. Also run `echo $PATH` as the vega user and confirm that `/home/vega/bin` is in the PATH variable. The error shows your user is trying to run the normal `/usr/bin/awk` command and not their own local `~/bin/awk`.

Comment: Hi @terdon 
I tried your step and am getting as below:

vega@VD1-21-2-1:~$ echo $PATH
/home/vega/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

without sudo it is not working:
admin@VD1-21-2-1:/home/vega$ ln -s /bin/ls /home/vega/bin
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/vega/bin/ls': Permission denied

tried via root also:
root@VD1-21-2-1:~# ln -s /bin/ls /home/vega/bin
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/vega/bin/ls': File exists


Simple I want a restricted user to access all my commands without any issues?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Again, as instructed before, please [edit] any additional info in your question and use code formatting as necessary! Your last comment is unreadable really and may drive users away from helping you!

Answer (score 0):

awk is not in /bin, it's in /usr/bin. So the command you need is

```
sudo ln -fs /usr/bin/awk /home/vega/bin
```

The -f flag will force the link to be replaced, you may need that given that you already have an invalid soft link.

You can check the location of any executable using which i.e.

```
which awk
```

and that will tell you where it's located.

Note that ssh is also in /usr/bin

Comment: above step done, still getting permission failed error: 
   admin@VD1-21-2-1:~/rusers$ ls -larth
   total 8.0K
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root  root     8 Oct 11 13:07 ssh -> /bin/ssh
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root  root    12 Nov  3 16:03 awk -> /usr/bin/awk
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root  root    13 Nov  3 16:03 gawk -> /usr/bin/gawk
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root  root    14 Nov  3 16:03 igawk -> /usr/bin/igawk
   drwxr-x--- 2 admin versa 4.0K Nov  3 16:03 .
   drwxr-x--- 7 admin versa 4.0K Nov  8 10:38 ..
   admin@VD1-21-2-1:~/rusers$ pwd
   /home/admin/rusers

Comment: add -f to force the ln to overwrite the existing invalid link.

Comment: the force option also didnt help and still getting the permission denied error

Comment: You'll have to use rm to remove the links then